# SQL Query using an anti-join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am defining "match" for use later on in some php, hence why I have defined it in the selection. I can't seem to get this query to work though... I get a parse error. Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    aif_id, 
    fee_source_id, 
    company_name_per_sedar, 
    document_filing_date, 
    NVL a_aif_remaining.aif_id, 0, 1 match
FROM a_aif, a_aif_remaining
LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
ORDER BY aif_id DESC;
```

This also doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    aif_id, 
    fee_source_id, 
    company_name_per_sedar, 
    document_filing_date, 
    CASE IF a_aif_remaining.aif_id  THEN 0 ELSE 1 match
FROM a_aif, a_aif_remaining
LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
ORDER BY aif_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason you're getting that error is because `MATCH` is a reserved word. You should escape it with backtick. Here are the list of reserved words

- [MySQL Reserved Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

try this, it should be `CASE WHEN...`

```
SELECT aif_id, 
       fee_source_id, 
       company_name_per_sedar, 
       document_filing_date, 
       CASE 
            WHEN a_aif_remaining.aif_id  IS NULL -- you should have condition on this line
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
       END `match`
FROM   a_aif
       LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining 
          ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
ORDER BY aif_id DESC;
```

if the value of the column is `NULL`, you can simply use `IF` (*to minimize the code*), eg

```
SELECT aif_id, 
       fee_source_id, 
       company_name_per_sedar, 
       document_filing_date, 
       IF(a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
FROM   a_aif
       LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining 
          ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
ORDER BY aif_id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks JW! Worked like a charm

Comment: check out this question here, I've made some updates:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/14251113/1788087